# How to improve performance while copying an image from one folder to another programmatically

Tags: android, image, gallery, rename

I made a custom gallery in which I can select multiple images and after that I perform the following steps:

1. Copy that image to another folder through File I/O
2. Rename the image while transfering to the destination folder

So while can I do both of these things, there is a long delay in between.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                for (int j=0;j<mTempFiles.size();j++){
                    try {
                        String path = mTempFiles.get(j);
                        String destination = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/BOM/";
                        File imgDest = new File(destination,"32_"+"Product" + new Date().getTime() + calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) + calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)  + ".png");
                        imgDest.createNewFile();

                        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imgDest);

                        File out = new File(path);
                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(out);
                        Bitmap imgBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);

                        ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        imgBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,byteOutput);
                        final byte[] imgBytes = byteOutput.toByteArray();
                        outputStream.write(imgBytes);
                        outputStream.close();

                        String dest = imgDest.getAbsolutePath();
                        compressImage(dest);
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(dest);
                        mPath.add(dest);
                        Constants.mCategoryModels.add(new CategoryModel(bitmap));

                        Constants.mFiles.add(imgDest);
                        Log.e("Main Array Size:----  ",""+Constants.mFiles.size());
```

Comment: Could you show us your code for copying files?

Comment: I have added the code please have a look at it @A.Omar

Comment: Why does your code involve some bitmap operation? You only want to copy an existing file and rename it, right ?

Comment: I m compressing the image before moving it to destination..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to copy a file:

```
private static void copyFile(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(source);
        os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int length;
        while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            // do stuff on buffer
            os.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    } finally {
        is.close();
        os.close();
    }
}

/* use it as follows */

File fileToCopy = new File(path);
File destinationFile = new File(path2);
copyFile(fileToCopy, destinationFile);
```